# Use SQL Query to join Current and Historical Data on Grid View

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, select, union

I have two database table to store the current data and another to store historical data, whenever a user makes any changes then the current table is updated and that data in the current data is saved to historical table. However, I would like to use a SQL query to display on the gridview both the current and historical data. I've outlined a picture of the results I would like to achieve.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for `union all`:

```
select ct.* from current_table
union all
select ht.* from history_table
```

For this to work properly, both tables must have the same number of columns, with the same datatype (and length) - the description of your question makes me think that this really is the case here.

Comment: The columns are not exact I have a column in the current table (status) and that is not going to show the current data followed by the historic data

Comment: @Sur: then you need to enumerate the columns in each `select` statement to retain only identical columns (or fill the missing column with `null`).

Comment: How would a user know that it is a historical data or current data

Answer (score 0):

Use as command for your sql query as below

```
select column1, column2 from table1
union
select column4 as column1, column2 from table2.
```

This will rename you non matching column to matching column.
Some reading [link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp)